# fontawesome only on -dev not visible but online

Tags: css, angular, font-awesome

I installed fontawesome with below cmd as suggested in their official site.

```
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

For production purpose I added below in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.0/css/all.css">
```

`ng serve` --> not displays icons when there is no internet connection i.e offline.

Importing `all.css` file in `style.css` like below is working in offline but in `ng serve` fa supporting files exporting to dist folder.

```
@import "../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
```

`ng build --prod` --> displays icons fine in 'online', as intended.

How do I see icons in offline with `ng serve`?

my `package.json` looks

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.5",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.2",
    ...
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.8.0",
    ...
  }
}
```

I am using this in Angular 7 project.

Comment: Download css file to local folder and set path on index html like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="localhost/fontawesomecss/all.css">`

Comment: Added like this but no luck <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css">

Answer (score 0):

You have to [download the pack from font awesome website](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself). This package includes css, js files as well as the woff, svg, eot etc.

In your HTML (DEV and PROD), instead of giving the CDN url `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.0/css/all.css">` you should give relative paths to your fonts directory which (sa per bast practice) should be in assets folder.

Something like:

```
@font-face {
      font-family: Ionicons;
      src: url(../assets/fonts/ioniconsAI.eot?v=2.0.1);
      src: url(../assets/fonts/ioniconsAI.eot?v=2.0.1#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../assets/fonts/ioniconsAI.ttf?v=2.0.1) format("truetype"), url(../assets/fonts/ioniconsAI.woff?v=2.0.1) format("woff"), url(../assets/fonts/ioniconsAI.svg?v=2.0.1#Ionicons) format("svg");
      font-weight: 400;
      font-style: normal
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do I ensure that in prod css files from CDNs?

Comment: in the HTML file you get after ng build, you can replace the relative link with the CDN link